# What contributes gate charge in a MOSFET besides gate-source capacitance and gate-drain capacitance?

Tags: mosfet, datasheet

I'm confused by the datasheet for the [FQB55N10](http://www.onsemi.com/PowerSolutions/product.do?id=FQB55N10TM):

[image]

75nC typical total gate charge = 13nC typical gate-source charge + 36nC typical gate-drain charge + 26nC typical gate charge from some other mystery source, namely... what? This is a three terminal device.

Comment: Charge is on the port itself. Gate-source or gate-drain is more like capacitance and voltage.

Comment: on the port.... ?

Comment: On MOSFET's pin. Just number of electrons, simply speaking

Comment: Um... this doesn't make sense to me. What kind of capacitance would store 26nC? Where is it physically located? That's a lot for a semiconductor, where parasitic capacitances are usually in the low picocoulombs.

Comment: You pump electrons to the gate, they push/pull others to the channel. Everything is fine, it's not intrinsic

Comment: but then that same gate charge should show up in the gate-source charge. Maybe this is just a terminology thing. (Or maybe they just miscalculated in the datasheet.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just a matter of how those charges are defined. Figure 12 in the datasheet you linked clearly explains it all

[image]

Those missing 25 nC or so are just gate "topping-up" after Miller plateau is over

Comment: ah.....! Thanks, that makes sense. Yeah, so it's terminology.

Answer (score 3):

A MOSFET is modeled as three capacitors as shown below.

As such the total capacitance is rather more complicated than just the sum of the Cgs and Cgd.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFTFog.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In fact in some MOSFETS there are other capacitances due to the construction.

Ultimately the capacitance also depends on the state and voltages involved.

Comment: I wasn't asking about capacitance, I was asking about charge... I know they are related by voltage, but it seems like conservation of charge applies. All I want to know is where the charge goes. If I have a gate drive chip that puts in 75nC into the gate, and 13nC goes into gate-source capacitance whereas 36nC goes into gate-drain capacitance, where does the other 26nC go?

Comment: @JasonS Cds.....

Comment: oh.... I guess that makes sense, given that the drain voltage changes during switching.

Comment: ...although the only way for charge to enter the gate-drain capacitance is via the gate (with corresponding charge exiting the drain); if charge goes into the drain-source capacitance via Cgd then the same amount of charge goes into both. So I am not sure I agree with that assertion that Cds gets the other 26nC.

Comment: In other words, physics doesn't care what happens to Cds: if you push 75nC through the gate, some of it goes into Cgs and the rest goes into Cgd. If there's another place for capacitive energy to be stored with a connection to the gate, it isn't shown on your diagram and I'm not aware of any other major capacitors.

Comment: @JasonS perhaps this will help http://www.polyfet.com/mosartcl.pdf